# Why is my Canon camera not turning on?

Tags: canon, troubleshooting, power

If I turn on my Canon camera a red light blinks but my camera is not turning on. There is no clicking sound and if I press any buttons nothing happens. What is wrong with the camera?

The battery is good, and sometimes the camera will turn on but if  turn it off then it won't turn on again.

Comment: Have you try to replace/charge the battery?

Comment: the battery is good, sometimes the camera will on and if i will turn it off then on it again it will not turning on again

Comment: Check the contacts of the battery in the body of camera. If the battery and contacts are OK probably there is internal problem/damage

Comment: Have you tried using a different memory card? Does the problem persist or go away?